# Why did Donald Knuth say that when implementing a circular queue with sequential allocation, overflow will not be detected when F = 0

Tags: data-structures, circular-list, circular-queue, taocp

In the 2.2.2 *sequential allocation section, TAOCP volume 1* , Donald Knuth mentions that `F = R = 0` is for the two cases (4) and (5) of the circular queue,
[image: 2.2.2 sequential allocation section, TAOCP volume 1 P244]

but if we use (6a) and (7a), we should set `F = R = 1`, otherwise "overflow will not be detected when F = 0".
[image: 2.2.2 sequential allocation section, TAOCP volume 1 P245]

If I change (6a) and (7a) as follows, **can the initial values of `F` and `R` also be 0**?

```
func enqueue(X, Y) {
    if R == M {
        R = 0 // <- rewind to 0
    } else {
        R = R + 1
    }
    if R == F {
        return error("OVERFLOW")
    }
    X[R] = Y
}

func dequeue(X, &Y) {
    if F == R {
        return error("UNDERFLOW")
    }
    if F == M {
        F = 0  // rewind to 0
    } else {
        F = F + 1
    }
    Y = X[F]
}
```

It seemed that this implementation only detects whether the queue is full(OVERFLOW) or empty(UNDERFLOW) when `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` are called, so there is no need to waste the 0th element and force `X[1]` to be adjacent to `X[M]` logically, skipping `X[0]`.

On the other hand, there is indeed a trick to reserve an element purposely to implement a circular queue. Reserving additional elements means that a circular queue with a capacity of `M` can only store `M-1` elements; in other words, to store `M` elements, it is required to allocate `M+1` space. The advantage of this approach is that we can determine whether the queue is full or empty without calling `enqueue()` and `dequeue()`. When `F = R`, the queue is empty and when `F = (R+1) mod M` the queue is full.

It looks like Donald Knuth didn't use this approach here, and I think there are no differences between `F = R = 1` and `F = R = 0`, if we modify (6a) and (7a) appropriately.

Comment: So did you *work exercise 1*?

Answer (score 0):

Using `M` nodes (of some `X` indexable with 1 to `M`), if you initialise `F`&`R` to 0 and try to insert `M`+1 elements following (6a), the last modification to `F` will take it to 1 with `R` still at 0:
The condition `R=F` from (6a) will be false, overflow go undetected.